# Views OOP approach - Let Views extend from Meta/Parent View

Tags: views

Hej.

On my Drupal Site I have several slider, all of them have the most in common but could differ in some way.

I'd like to have a View as Meta/Parent View so that if something is changed it will be changed in the Child Views as well. But every Child View could have their own attributes or adaptions.

I know there is the Display Section in the View but if I add a View or Display and change something, it effects every view even the Master Display.

Is there something like a View OOP approach in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change something on any of the different displays (other than master), there should be combobox at the top that says "for" which defaults to "All Displays" meaning that the change will apply to all displays. But you can select "This Block" or "This Page" so that the change only happens to that particular display.

Also, if you go into views settings "admin/structure/views/settings" you can set "Always show the master display" which I usually do.

Comment: Ok, thanks, good to know. I never noticed that checkbox. Do you know if there is a possibility to set that to default in Child-Views/-Displays?

Comment: I don't think you can set it, it always defaults to "All Displays"